# show no data available message when ng-options is empty in select?

Tags: angularjs

I have created an select element as

```
<label class="item item-select no-border-bottom padding full-width custom-back">
  <div class="input-label">Select Time Slot</div>
   <select ng-model="addAppointment.timeSlot" name="timeSlot" class="custom-back" ng-disabled="!addAppointment.date" ng-options="timeSlot as timeSlot for timeSlot in availableTimeSlots" required>
    </select>
</label>
```

I would like a option having message `No Data` in select when ng-options array is empty.

Comment: Why don't you hide the select and display a message instead ?
<select data-ng-show="availableTimeSlots.length > 0"></select><span data-ng-show="availableTimeSlots.length === 0">No Data</span>

Comment: i could do that...but is it possible to show it via an option in select.

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think so. You could use a <option ng-repeat=""> coupled with the ng-if aswell but I guess it's still not what you are searching for. Or push a non-selectable value in availableTimeSlots when there is none

Answer (score 1):

You could add an `<option>` with `ng-if` to your select. Here is a contrived example of how this would work.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.options = [];
    $scope.selectedOption = undefined;
    
    $scope.addOptions = function() {
      var start = $scope.options.length;
      for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        $scope.options.push('Option #' + (start + i));
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="opt as opt for opt in options">
    <option value="" ng-if="options.length === 0">No Data</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" ng-click="addOptions()">Add Options</button> 
</div>
```